# raspberry pi motion permission issue

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, raspberry-pi3

I have installed motion on raspberry pi and once I make a "motion/movement" in front of the camera it crashes.

Errors are the following:

```
Nov  9 14:49:55 raspberrypi motion: [1] [ERR] [ENC] ffmpeg_open: url_fopen - error opening file /var/lib/motion/01-20161109144955.avi ... check access rights to target directory:
Nov  9 14:49:55 raspberrypi motion: [1] [ERR] [EVT] event_ffmpeg_newfile: ffopen_open error creating (new) file [/var/lib/motion/01-20161109144955.avi]:
Nov  9 14:49:55 raspberrypi motion: [1] [NTC] [ALL] motion_detected: Motion detected - starting event 1
Nov  9 14:49:55 raspberrypi motion: [1] [ERR] [ALL] myfopen: Error opening file /var/lib/motion/01-20161109144955-03.jpg with mode w:
Nov  9 14:49:55 raspberrypi motion: [1] [ERR] [ALL] put_picture: Can't write picture to file /var/lib/motion/01-20161109144955-03.jpg - check access rights to target directory#012Thread is going to finish due to this fatal error:
Nov  9 14:49:55 raspberrypi motion: [1] [ERR] [ALL] myfopen: Error opening file /var/lib/motion/01-20161109144955-04.jpg with mode w:
Nov  9 14:49:55 raspberrypi motion: [1] [ERR] [ALL] put_picture: Can't write picture to file /var/lib/motion/01-20161109144955-04.jpg - check access rights to target directory#012Thread is going to finish due to this fatal error:
```

I understand that this is to do with permissions, but I have created motion directory in `/tmp` and set `chown motion:motion motion`, which from my understanding shouldn't give that type of error.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by your pasted log excerpt, the file writing occurs in the `/var/lib/motion/` directory. So if you'd correct that directory's permissions, it should work. Or change the application's settings to write to the /tmp/motion directory.

See the `target_dir` option for motion on http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/ConfigFileOptions